# How do I modify a JSON file with React?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

I want to modify a JSON file in react. Is there any way to do so?

I have this code which is run when I click on an html element. At the end it calls VoteTracking which is the function where I actually modify my json file.

```
    handleChange(val){
            const { voted, score, imgup, imgdown, deviceKey } = this.state;
            const { id } = this.props;
            var x = this.state.score, vote = val;

            var clr;
            if (val) clr="#d98832"; else clr = "#3d3dff";

            if(!voted) {
                x += val;
                this.setState({voted: val, score: x, color: clr });
            }
            else if(Math.abs(voted)){
                if (voted == val){
                    vote = 0;
                    x -= val;
                    this.setState({voted: 0, score: x, color: "#6e6e6e"});
                }
                else {
                    x += (2* val);
                    this.setState({score: x, voted: val, color: clr});
                }
            }

            VoteTracking(this.props.id, deviceKey, vote);
    }
```

This is my VoteTracking.js

```
const VoteTracking = function(ident, deviceKey, vote){
  var fs = require('fs');
  var m = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('VoteList.json').toString());

  var containsID = false;
  var found = false;

  m.forEach(function(p){
    if ( p.id == ident ) {
        containsID = true;

        for(var i in p.upvotes){
            var temp = p.upvotes[i];
            if ( temp == deviceKey){
                p.upvotes.splice(i, 1);
                console.log(i)
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found){
            for(var i in p.downvotes){
                var temp = p.downvotes[i];
                if ( temp == deviceKey){
                    p.downvotes.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        switch (vote) {
            case 1: {
                p.upvotes.push(deviceKey);
                break;
            }
            case -1: {
                p.downvotes.push(deviceKey);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
  });

  if (!containsID){
    if (vote){
        m.push(
                {
                    id: ident,
                    upvotes: [deviceKey],
                    downvotes: []
                }
        );
    }
    else if (vote == -1 ){
        m.push(
                {
                    id: ident,
                    upvotes: [],
                    downvotes: [deviceKey]
                }
        );
    }
  }

  fs.writeFile('VoteList.json', JSON.stringify(m, null, "\t"));
};

module.exports = VoteTracking;
```

Which works if I used node, but is there any way for react to do this?

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: I think it should still work with react if it is working with node. try printing out your json file in react and making sure the file path is still correct.

Comment: It says that the module fs is not found, do I have to run `npm i -S fs`     
**Edit** - Even if I install fs it still says that the module is not resolved

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention that you click on an element to trigger file modification, I assume that your React program runs in a browser. While `fs` is part of the Node runtime, for security reasons there is no such thing in browser runtimes, except for some proprietary [extensions](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

As a workaround, the React page could send the JSON document to the server, which is able to store the file, or download it back to the client machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the delayed answer. Could you please explain how I could send the JSON doc to the server for storage, and load it back up on browser

Comment: That will take some work. To send the document the server, compose an AJAX POST request. To get the file back, the server must anwer some specific HTTP response. Google all this, it will not fit in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not let you access the filesystem so you cannot use fs within the front-end portion of your app.