# How to update json file in axios (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, axios, file-writing

I am currently mock data for my react application. So axios is used for mock the data and those mock data is stored in json file. My json file as below.

```
{
 "invoices": [{
 "storageId": 45678,
 "identifier": "1215",
 "invoiceDate": "2119-05-10",
 "invoiceNo": "11",
 "issuer": "Oliver",
 "totalAmount": 321533,
 "status": "Rejected",
 "dueDate": "1019-01-15",
 "netAmount": 1000,
 "vatAmount": 10,
 "downloadLink":"http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
 }]
}
```

once I change the status of invoice it need to be updated in the json file. So i need a way to update or override existing json file with new data. I fount the fs solution and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755470/how-do-i-modify-a-json-file-with-react

Comment: @ShantiswarupTunga But cannot find the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.server for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

you create json file called:   db.json, put all your data into it, and then it becomes a MOCK database/API... simulating Express/MondoDB environment in a way.

Its very good.

Just read the NPM guide its super easy to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server

All get/post/delete/patch/put work identical to  Express Server, so just pretend that this is an Express server and use the same code in Axios as if it was Express Server and it will work.